# LinQ Aggregate Error - Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate, sequence

Please help me here. I have a LinQ Query with many filter conditions.

Below is my query:

```
var Aggregate = linqkb.Where(s => s.Status.Equals("Approved")).Select(s => s.Approver)
    .Distinct()
    .Aggregate((i, j) => i + ";" + j)
    .Split(';')
    .Distinct();
```

In some cases, i am getting the error:

```
Error Message : Sequence contains no elements
Stack Trace   : at System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 func)
```

I am new to linQ. Please suggest.

I have googled and tried using  `**.DefaultIfEmpty()**` before `Aggregator` as shown below:

```
var Aggregate = linqkb.Where(s => s.Status.Equals("Approved")).Select(s => s.Approver)
    .Distinct()
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Aggregate((i, j) => i + ";" + j)
    .Split(';')
    .Distinct();
```

But this doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `linqkb` and what type are the elements of in this sequence?

Comment: You can try to split the calls and debug the intermediate results. Possibly there is no element with `Status = "Approved"`. `DefaultIfEmpty` only provides another empty sequence afaik.

Comment: Why are you joining by `";"` only to split it again on the next line? The simplest fix to the exception is to provide an initial value to `Aggregate` i.e. `Aggregate("", (i, j) => i + ";" + j)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Aggregate` uses the first item in the sequence as the accumulator if none is provided. This can't be done if there are no items in the sequence, so in that case an exception is thrown. You can provide an explicit initial value i.e.

```
.Aggregate(string.Empty, (i, j) => i + ";" + j)
```

Be aware that this method of joining strings is inefficient and creates a lot of intermediate garbage. You could use `string.Join` although it's not clear why you immediately split the result on `";"` in the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Direct solution for the issue is as follows:

```
var Aggregate = linqkb
    .Where(s => s.Status.Equals("Approved"))
    .Select(s => s.Approver)
    .Distinct()
    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (i, j) => i + ";" + j)
    .Split(';')
    .Distinct();
```

i.e. you should use overload of Aggregate with seed parameter.

However yours query looks quite wired. In case if you just want distinct values of Approver field it is enough to use following construct:

```
var Aggregate = linqkb
    .Where(s => s.Status.Equals("Approved"))
    .Select(s => s.Approver)
    .Distinct();
```

In case if Approver field contains values separated with ";" and you want to extract them and get distinct list then you should use:

```
var Aggregate = linqkb
    .Where(s => s.Status.Equals("Approved"))
    .SelectMany(s => s.Approver.Split(";"))
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is what is says, there are no elements. `linqkb.Where(s => s.Status.Equals("Approved"))` returns empty set. Aggregation can't run over it. You can use `Any()` for check. Also your joining with `';'` and later doing `Distinct` doesn't do anything really.

```
var Aggregate = linqkb.Where(s => s.Status.Equals("Approved"))                                                                               .Select(s => s.Approver)
   .Distinct();

if (!Aggreate.Any())
return ...;
```